# White space on iOS - can't add overflow-x: hidden to HTML without breaking menu

Tags: jquery, html, ios, css

I have the following code to remedy this issue:

```
html, body {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}
```

This works on desktop. However, this does not render properly on iOS. I can scroll to the far left, exposing a white gap. When I have

```
overflow-x: hidden;
```

on the html it remedies the issue. However I cannot use this because it will break the jQuery menu I am using, [SlickNav](http://slicknav.com/), which hides the rest of the content on the page, since it converts from tabbed navigation on desktop and a one-pager on mobile.

I have an unordered list on the page that has a width of 100%, which is breaking out of a container that I have set to 1100px. I tried removing the ul which helped, but a white space was still present.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: can you post all of your html and css in the snippet code editor? Hit Ctrl + M to open it

Comment: if you have left / right padding or border on that list, you need to add `box-sizing:border-box` to the class.  If you have left / right margin, then you will need to set the width like `width: calc(100% - [margin_amount]px)` obviously replacing the [margin_amount].  As you have not provided an [MCVE], this is a complete guess as to what your problem is

Comment: Pete you were right - I needed that but I had to add it to my container. Thanks!